# Creating a Unity 3D game and need portals

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making an open world game, and I want to put loading screens in between areas to make it less computer-intense. There is going to be a fast-travel teleport solution, but I want people to role play a bit. Basically, I have a starting area made. How can I create a new area that can be connected but isn't loaded at the same time as the previous? Also, when you walk onto a certain part of the map, I want the player to be sent to the other place. I also want them to be able to see the area they are going to (I know there is a way to do this on paid version but there must be a way to mirror it with raw code). Thanks! If there isn't a good solution on free version, I might have access to paid soon, so I just need to know how to create the separate but connectable area. Thanks, hopefully I didn't repeat myself too much!

Comment: How can the player _"see the area they are going to"_ when it _"isn't loaded at the same time as the previous"_.  Since you are teleporting the player and not using airlocks or _streaming worlds_, why not just load up a new scene and replace the old one.

Comment: Ahh, so like minecraft's chunk loading? How could I do that, or would it happen automatically if I made a large enough terrain?